# Password not changing of user

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to change the password of the user via a form but it never changes, It says password changed but it always stays the same.

views.py

```
@login_required
def userchange(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        old_password = request.POST['Old password']
        new_password1 = request.POST['New password1']
        new_password2 = request.POST['New password2']
        print(new_password1)
        print(new_password2)
        if user.check_password(old_password):
            if new_password1 == new_password2:
                if new_password1 == "" or new_password2 == "":
                    return render(request, 'main/change.html', {'error':'Your new passwords are empty!'})
                else:
                    User.objects.get(username=request.user.username).set_password(new_password1)
                    logout(request)
                return render(request, 'main/change.html', {'error':'Your password has been changed succesfully!'})
            else:
                return render(request, 'main/change.html', {'error':'Your new passwords do not match'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'main/change.html', {'error':'Your old password is incorrect'})
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'main/change.html')
```

change.html

```
<h1>Note: You will be logged out</h1>
<h2>{{ error }}</h2>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="password" placeholder="Old password" name="Old password">
    <input type="password" placeholder="New password" name="New password1">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" name="New password2">
    <button type="submit">Change password</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to call 'save' on that user instance most likely.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password as documented does not call save, also why don't you use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/ moreover there is PasswordChangeView https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have changed password but not saved. So:

```
@login_required
def userchange(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        old_password = request.POST['Old password']
        new_password1 = request.POST['New password1']
        new_password2 = request.POST['New password2']
        print(new_password1)
        print(new_password2)
        if user.check_password(old_password):
            if new_password1 == new_password2:
                if new_password1 == "" or new_password2 == "":
                    return render(request, 'main/change.html', {'error':'Your new passwords are empty!'})
                else:
                    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
                    user.set_password(new_password1)
                    user.save()
                    logout(request)
                return render(request, 'main/change.html', {'error':'Your password has been changed succesfully!'})
            else:
                return render(request, 'main/change.html', {'error':'Your new passwords do not match'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'main/change.html', {'error':'Your old password is incorrect'})
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'main/change.html')
```

[Changing passwords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords)